# Cannot upload files to server

Tags: craft-pro

I have a strange issue, I can't upload files to the server.

The error message is

`Error uploading the file: The folder craft/storage/runtime/assets/tempuploads/user_7/field_101 does not exist`

The stranger thing is that another person working on the same project, with the same rights as me (admin) can perfectly upload files. 
Once he does that, I can upload files to that same location too

There is no folder called "user_7" in tempuploads. Just field_52, field_54, etc.

Comment: Where are you trying to upload the file from in the CP?  From the main Assets index page? From an Assets field?  If the latter, what are the field settings set to?

Comment: It is an asset field, it is set to a created asset source (path being `{basePath}/uploads/images/`), with a dynamic subfolder `{section.handle}`

Comment: Does this happen for all types of files (pdf, jpg, png, etc.) or just specific ones?  Are you using GD or Imagick on that box? What versions?

Comment: It happens with all types of files, I'm using Imagick with the following versions :
http://imgur.com/a/hOvlF